# Program Freezes with Multithreading

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have a python program which has a function `takeScreenshot` that takes a screenshot of 10 webpages that are inputted. I want to use threading to make the web scraping part of taking the screenshot be executed in the background while the program goes on inputting more webpages. After taking 10 screenshots, they should be displayed in the program.

The question is how to make the program display them after the last `takeScreenshot` thread (the tenth thread) is done so as not to cause an error? In other words, how to make sure that all the threads are finished? I tried to make a list of all the threads that started and make them `.join()` after inputting the last webpage (in the last loop). However, this makes the program freeze after inputting the last webpage.

```
threads=[]
n=0
while n<10:
   webpage = input("Enter the webpage")
   thread = threading.Thread(target = takeScreenshot, args = webpage)
   thread.start()
   threads.append(thread)
   if n==9:
      for thread in threads:
         thread.join()
   n++
```

I tried to investigate more, so I discovered that the program freezes in the last loop when it sets an attribute of a class equal to the screenshot: `self.graph = PhotoImage(file='screenshot.png')`. Note that the screenshot of the last webpage is normally downloaded, so the error isn't due to the absence of the screenshot. The previous line of code is included in the `takeScreenshot` function.

Here's the `takeScreenshot` method (it's a part of a class called `scraping`:

```
ublockPath = r'C:\Users\Bassel Attia\Documents\Trading Core\1.37.2_0'
chromeOptions = Options()
chromeOptions.add_argument("--log-level=3")
chromeOptions.add_argument('load-extension=' + ublockPath)
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), 
chrome_options=chromeOptions)   
    
self.driver.get(webpage)
self.driver.get_screenshot_as_file('screenshot.png')
self.image = Image.open('screenshot.png')

#crop screenshot
area = (20, 290, 1250, 800)
croppedImage=self.image.crop(area)
os.remove('currentStock.png')
croppedImage.save('screenshot.png')
self.image = Image.open('screenshot.png')

#resizeImage
newHeight = 300
newWidth = int(newHeight / self.image.height * self.image.width)
resizedImage = self.image.resize((newWidth, newHeight))
os.remove('currentStock.png')
resizedImage.save('screenshot.png')
self.image = Image.open('screenshot.png')
self.image.close()

self.driver.quit()
```

Comment: I don't understand you. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: I would suggest that you use a [`multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool) because you could submit all the tasks to it you want, and then call its `join()` method to wait for them all to finish. **Or** you could so something similar with the `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` as suggested in the linked documentation.

Comment: The snippet of code you've submitted looks right to me. `.join()` waits for the thread to finish. I'm positive that the bug is in the takeScreenshot function

Comment: @alec I updated the post to include `takeScreenshot` function. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

By inspecting the code you provided unfortunately i wasn't able to reproduce the issue, but there are some things that could be problematic:

- the file currentStock.png is deleted twice (which i'm surprised it doesn't raise an exception the second time you try to delete it)
- you keep overwriting the same 'screenshot.png' file
- args is not a list

If this could help, here it is a minimum working example:

```py
import os, io, threading, uuid
from PIL import Image
from selenium import webdriver


def screen(wid, webpage):
    opts = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
    opts.add_argument('--headless')
    print(wid, 'starting webdriver')
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=opts)
    driver.get(webpage)
    print(wid, 'taking screenshot')

    image_data = driver.get_screenshot_as_png()
    image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_data))

    area = (20, 290, 1250, 800)
    cropped = image.crop(area)

    h = 300
    w = int(h / cropped.height * cropped.width)
    resized = cropped.resize((w, h))

    if not os.path.isdir('screen'):
        os.mkdir('screen')
    fname = os.path.join('screen', f'{uuid.uuid4()}.png')

    resized.save(fname)
    print(wid, f'screenshot saved to {fname}')
    driver.quit()


def main():
    threads = []
    for wid in range(4):
        webpage = input('Webpage: ')
        thread = threading.Thread(target = screen, args = [wid, webpage])
        thread.start()
        threads.append(thread)

    for i, thread in enumerate(threads):
        thread.join()
        print('joined thread : ', i)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```